# C#: How can DateTime.Now be just an attribute?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to understand how the implementation of the `Now` attribute in `DateTime` works. My background is mainly Python and Haskell so I can't by my life understand how the `Now` attribute can "return" different values depending on when you use it.

My intuition says that `Now` should really be a function which does some low-level magic followed by some high-level magic and then returns a DateTime object with the correct time.

Comment: Its one of the few places (if not the only place) in the framework which goes against the convention...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DateTime.Now isn't an attribute, it's a static readonly property.

Under the covers a readonly property is just a function call that returns a value, so it can do any amount of processing it wants to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, same goes for `DateTime.Today`, `DateTime.UtcNow`

Answer (score 4):

It's not an attribute, it's a static property on the DateTime class that looks like the following:

```
public static DateTime Now
{
    get
    {
        return UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

UtcNow is another property on DateTime that returns the following:

```
return new DateTime((ulong) ((GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() + 
  0x701ce1722770000L) | 0x4000000000000000L));
```

GetSystemTimeAsFileTime is a Windows API Call.